# Scipy odeint function of multiple variables

Tags: python, scipy

I wish to solve a **second order differential equation**, where *the target function is a function of two variables*.

The equation reads

> del^2 (p) = - exp(p)
>
> where p is a function of R and z.

Following the procedure from the `scipy.integrate.odeint` documentation, I rewrite this a set of four first order differential equations.

```
q = dp/dR 

s = dp/dz

dq/dR = - exp(p) - ds/dz - q/R

ds/dz = - exp(p) - (q+R dq/dR)/R
```

With `y = [p, q, s]` I can set up initial conditions like `y0 = [p0, 0, 0]`.

My question is how one sets up the derivative function. In a 1 variables case you would have something like

```
def deriv(y, r, params):
     p, q = y
     dydr = [q, f(p,q)]
     return dydr
```

However, if one were to do that with a two variable case the line

```
dydr = [....]
```

would contain derivatives with respect to different things.
Is there an obvious way around this, or is my approach entirely wrong?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are dealing with a partial differential equation (two varianles: R and z), whereas according to documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) this method is meant for ordinary differential equations (just one variable, e.g. time).

Comment: Scipy documentaion lists an example od solving a PDE with `scipy.integrate.odeint`, but in order to do that they:
"discretize the x variable by defining the uniformly spaced grid of points " and in fact then, they integrate only in time (so, they are left with one variable). See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html